# Subset a pandas dataframe that has an index that contains duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

For the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': [1,2,3,4,5, np.nan, np.nan],
    'value': ['one','two','three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
}).set_index('key')
```

That looks like this:

```
        value
key     
1.0     one
2.0     two
3.0     three
4.0     four
5.0     five
NaN     six
NaN     seven
```

I would like to subset it to:

```
    value
key     
1   one
1   one
6   NaN
```

This produces a warning:

```
df.loc[[1,1,6],]

Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

This produces an error:

```
df.reindex([1, 1, 6])

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

How to do it while referencing a missing index and without using apply?

Comment: I had answered but it actually depends on your pandas version.. what version are you using ?

Comment: pd.__version__ '0.23.3'

Comment: @adpatter then I believe my answer holds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you have duplicated values `NaN`s as indexes. You should disconsider those when reindexing because they are duplicates and there is ambiguity on which value use in the new index.

```
df.loc[df.index.dropna()].reindex([1, 1, 6])

    value
key 
1   one
1   one
6   NaN
```

For a generalized solution, use `duplicated`

```
df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep=False)].reindex([1, 1, 6])
```

If you want to keep duplicated indexes and use `reindex`, you'll fail. This [has actually been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986989/reindex-a-dataframe-with-duplicate-index-values) a couple of times