# Unpivot Dataframe w/ Partial String

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (totaldf) such that:

```
           ...     Hom   ...    March Plans   March Ships   April Plans   April Ships   ...

0                  CAD   ...    12              5           4             13
1                  USA   ...    7               6           2             11
2                  CAD   ...    4               9           6             14
3                  CAD   ...    13              3           9             7
...                ...   ...    ...             ...         ...           ...
```

for all months of the year. I would like it to be:

```
           ...     Hom   ...    Month   Plans    Ships    ...

0                  CAD   ...    March    12          5             
1                  USA   ...    March    7           6             
2                  CAD   ...    March    4           9             
3                  CAD   ...    March    13          3
4                  CAD   ...    April    4           13            
5                  USA   ...    April    2           11             
6                  CAD   ...    April    6           14             
7                  CAD   ...    April    9           7
...                ...   ...    ...      ...         ...
```

Is there an easy way to do this without splitting string entries?
I have played around with `totaldf.unstack()` but since there are multiple columns I'm unsure as to how to properly reindex the dataframe.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.

Comment: @meW I thought that I did that. Could you explain why this doesn't meet the criteria so I may correct it? Edit: I tried to format my question exactly like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259067/unpivot-pandas-data and I see no difference in the quality or quantity of information. Please advise me where I went wrong.

Comment: Give a code to generate the above examples, even a sample will work. Also, add what have you tried so far. The above link gives complete desc of what I'm referring to. Also, [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @meW the reason I chose to exclude the code used to produce the dataframe is because it is a lengthy concatenation and rearranging of multiple dataframes. It's too long to look through and no one part provides a clear enough demonstration of how the dataframe has been created, hence I opted to omit it as I didn't think that it was pertinent to my example. The column names are there and both the sample output and desired output are included so I'm not too sure what's missing.

Comment: @ALollz I stated in the question at the top that columns exist for every month of the year. I will make the output more sensible.

Comment: @poorpractice Your expected output values are hard to correlate with original data. Also, I see 2 March within Month! Better add in question how are you arriving on them.

Comment: @meW
I fixed the output, hopefully this makes more sense now as it matches!

Comment: @ALollz I changed the output to match so that it makes sense now, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), with a little extra work in order to have the right `stubnames`, given that as mentioned in the docs:

> The stub name(s). The wide format variables are assumed to start with the stub names.

So it will be necessary to slightly modify the column names so that the stubnames are at the beginning of each column name:

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('Plans|Ships')
cols = df.columns[m].str.split(' ')
df.columns.values[m] = [w+month for month, w in cols]

print(df)
   Hom  PlansMarch  ShipsMarch  PlansApril  ShipsApril
0  CAD          12           5           4          13
1  USA           7           6           2          11
2  CAD           4           9           6          14
3  CAD          13           3           9           7
```

Now you can use `pd.wide_to_long` using `['Ships', 'Plans']` as stubnames in order to obtain the output you want:

```
((pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['Ships', 'Plans'], i = 'index', 
                j = 'Month', suffix='\w+')).reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
                .reset_index())

x  Month  Hom  Ships  Plans
0  March  CAD      5     12
1  March  USA      6      7
2  March  CAD      9      4
3  March  CAD      3     13
4  April  CAD     13      4
5  April  USA     11      2
6  April  CAD     14      6
7  April  CAD      7      9
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yatu.

I updated my original example to include the fact that there are several additional columns in between the "Hom" column and the desired "Month" column. Will this affect the implementation of your solution at al?

Comment: I've added a small change to take this into consideration. Should work now @poorpractice :-)

Comment: I receive "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type" in line"totaldf.columns[m].str.split(' ')

Comment: I added another update, did u try with the latest version? @poorpractice

Comment: now I get, in line: totaldf.columns.values[m] = [w+month for month, w in cols] a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: `df.columns[m].str.split(' ')` is assuming the columns like `March Plans` have a space between them. Make sure thats the case

Comment: I'm dumb, I don't know how I could have missed that

Comment: Finally managed to get it working, thank you! Last question - if I'd like to keep the "month" column in the current position, i.e. after all columns but before Ships/Plans, what would my best course of action be?

Comment: For that do `final_df[['Hom','Month','Ships','Plans']]`. Don't forget to accept if it solved it for you :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you convert the columns to a MultiIndex you can use stack:

```
In [11]: df1 = df.set_index("Hom")

In [12]: df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1.columns.map(lambda x: tuple(x.split())))

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
    March       April
    Plans Ships Plans Ships
Hom
CAD    12     5     4    13
USA     7     6     2    11
CAD     4     9     6    14
CAD    13     3     9     7

In [14]: df1.stack(level=0)
Out[14]:
           Plans  Ships
Hom
CAD April      4     13
    March     12      5
USA April      2     11
    March      7      6
CAD April      6     14
    March      4      9
    April      9      7
    March     13      3
```

---

```
In [21]: res = df1.stack(level=0)

In [22]: res.index.names = ["Hom", "Month"]

In [23]: res.reset_index()
Out[23]:
   Hom  Month  Plans  Ships
0  CAD  April      4     13
1  CAD  March     12      5
2  USA  April      2     11
3  USA  March      7      6
4  CAD  April      6     14
5  CAD  March      4      9
6  CAD  April      9      7
7  CAD  March     13      3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I tried this solution (I have additional columns which are between the 'Hom' column and the 'Month' column so I tried just including them in the index names. I receive an error "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis".
I'm assuming that somewhere in my code I can include an "allow duplicates" parameter? Or do I need to do something else? I will update my original dataframe.

Comment: It's coming from line "df1.stack(level=0)"

Comment: If I call 'print(totaldf.columns)'  I get:
'Index(['Hom', 'Origin', 'Contract', 'Customer', 'Destination', 'C/O Party',
       'Summer', 'Pre-Winter', 'Winter', 'LD/Offload', 'March Plans', March Ships', 'April Plans', 'April Ships', ...],
      dtype='object')'

Comment: I did write the totaldf.set_index("Hom") and it doesn't appear to be having any issues there

Comment: I used index_series = pandas.Series(df1.index.values) and then print(index_series.value_counts()). It would appear that the duplicates are in the "Hom" column by ROWS

Comment: @poorpractice but that's also true in the original example / my code above.

Comment: you're absolutely correct, but for some reason that's what's causing the error? Edit: I found that code from this post, perhaps this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986989/reindex-a-dataframe-with-duplicate-index-values

Comment: @poorpractice i don't think so. Are there duplicate columns?

Comment: No duplicate columns whatsoever

Comment: Try dropping the columns which don't match "Month Thing"

Comment: I dropped all columns between Loc and the first "March" entry, and still received the same erorr.